# Verificação de Versões do Browser

Tags: cross-browser

Estou fazendo um site e gostaria de colocar uma verificação de navegadores que o usuário está utilizando.

Eu não quero que o site seja utilizado no IE 6, 7 e 8. Além de algumas versões do Firefox antigas que tem naqueles ambientes Linux.

Caso o navegador do usuário sejam alguns desses antigos quero redirecionar o usuário para uma página onde ele pode fazer o download de um navegador mais recente.

Mas estou pensando se esses navegadores antigos entendem o jQuery, porquê estava pensando em fazer uma rotina por meio dessa biblioteca.

Ou tem alguma outra maneira de fazer isso ? Eu não conheço.

Comment: Você pode utilizar tanto `JavaScript`, quanto `CSS` para fazer a verificação do browser do usuário, você também pode utilizar uma linguagem que está rodando no `back-end`, como o `PHP` por exemplo.... no seu caso aconselho utilizar `JavaScript`, pra isso também será necessário ter um certo conhecimento em `RegEx`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use o http://modernizr.com

Adicione ao header isto:

```
<script src="/js/vendor/modernizr.min.js"></script>
```

E no final da página isto:

```
<script>
// Detecta se o navegador é antigo
if(Modernizr.mq('only all') === false) {
   // Navegadores modernos suportam "Media Query", se o navegador não tiver suporte então direciona com location
   window.location.href = "http://exemplo/upgrade";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

O endereço `http://exemplo/upgrade` é o local de onde irá ter os links para os navegadores novos.

Comment: Eu uso esse modernizr nos meus sites. Pelo visto não sei usar direito! uahuhauah Guilherme, é somente isso ?

Comment: Sim @DiegoSouza este método verifica o suporte a media-query, que hoje em dia tem em todos navegadores modernos, se não tiver suporte é igual a `false` então usamos `window.location` :)

Comment: Entendi, Man. Valeu, vou implementar e já retorno!

Comment: Deu certo. Eu testei no IE 5, 6 e 7. Redirecionou para uma página que estou criando agora para o usuário atualizar o navegador.

Comment: Tem um detalhe. Eu tenho um preloader num site específico aqui. Tem como essa rotina rodar até mesmo antes desse preloader carregado no window.load com jQuery ?

Comment: @DiegoSouza ele roda antes do preloader sim, só não roda antes do $.ready, recomendo você fazer assim: `if(Modernizr.mq('only all') === false) {
   window.location.href = "http://exemplo/upgrade";
} else {
    /*inicia o preloder*/
}`

Comment: Entendo. Mas os navegadores antigos entendem o jQuery ?

Comment: @DiegoSouza eu não estou entendendo, você quer rodar o preloader após o usuário baixar a nova versão ou quer que funcione em qualquer browser. Até aonde entedi você quer forçar o usuário a baixar um navegador moderno primeiro. Se é isto o "preloader" só deve rodar se `Modernizr.mq('only all')` for igual a `true`, ou seja suportar tecnologias novas :)

Comment: Não mano... esquece isso que você falou agora. Eu tenho um preloader. Quero que a rotina de verificação de browser rode antes do preloader. Beleza ? Ou seja, quando a rotina ver que o browser não é compatível, ele nem chega carregar o preloader. Mas esse preloader é carregado por $.ready, isto é, jQuery. A pergunta é: os navegadores antigos interpretam jQuery ? Entendem o $.ready ?

Comment: @DiegoSouza o que você disse foi o mesmo que eu disse, o exemplo que postei nem chega no onload e provavelmente é disparado antes do `$.ready`.